# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [5,3] vs. [5]

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

I am trying to compose a cVAE model in keras. However, I keep getting the error: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [5,3] vs. [5]
[[{{node training/Adam/gradients/gradients/loss/model_1_loss/add_4_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]]

The following is my code:

```
import pre_keypoint as pk
import pre_sensor_data as psd

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import (Input, Dense, Lambda, Flatten, Reshape, 
                                            concatenate, Conv2D, LeakyReLU)
from keras.models import Model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import disable_eager_execution
disable_eager_execution()

X_train_acce = psd.get_agm(psd.chuck_data(), "Accelerometer")
y_train_acce = pk.get_keypoint()

X_train_acce = np.array(X_train_acce, dtype=np.float32)
y_train_acce = np.array(y_train_acce, dtype=np.float32)

X_train_acce = X_train_acce[:int(len(X_train_acce) * 0.8)]
X_test_acce = X_train_acce[int(len(X_train_acce) * 0.8):]
y_train_acce = y_train_acce[:int(len(y_train_acce) * 0.8)]
y_test_acce = y_train_acce[int(len(y_train_acce) * 0.8):]

print(X_train_acce.shape, y_train_acce.shape, X_test_acce.shape, y_test_acce.shape)

# batch_size = 64 
latent_size= 2  # latent space size
encoder_dim1 = 512  # dim of encoder hidden layer
decoder_dim = 512  # dim of decoder hidden layer
activ = 'relu'
optim = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
n_epoch = 100

mu = None
sigma = None

seconds = 3
frequency_x = 100
frequency_y = 10

decoder_out_dim = seconds * frequency_x * 3  # dim of decoder output layer

def sample_z(args):
    mu, sigma = args
    eps = K.random_normal(shape=( latent_size,), mean=0., stddev=1.)#batch_size,
    return mu + K.exp(sigma / 2) * eps

def build_cvae_encoder():
    global mu, sigma
    x_input = Input(shape=(seconds * frequency_x, 3))
    y_input = Input(shape=(seconds * frequency_y, 2))

    y = Dense(3)(y_input)

    inputs = concatenate([x_input, y], axis=1)
    encoder_h = Dense(encoder_dim1, activation=activ)(inputs) # shape: (None, 330, 512)

    mu = Dense(latent_size, activation='linear')(encoder_h) # shape: (None, 330, 2)
    sigma = Dense(latent_size, activation='linear')(encoder_h) # shape: (None, 330, 2)

    mu = K.mean(mu, axis=1)
    sigma = K.std(sigma, axis=1)

    print("mu.shape: ", mu.shape, "sigma.shape: ", sigma.shape)
    z = Lambda(sample_z, output_shape=(latent_size,))([mu, sigma])
    print("z.shape: ", z.shape)
    encoder_model = Model([x_input, y_input], z)
    encoder_model.summary()
    return encoder_model

def build_cvae_decoder():
    z_input = Input(shape=(latent_size))
    y_input = Input(shape=(seconds * frequency_y, 2))
    y = Flatten()(y_input)
    zc = concatenate([z_input, y], axis=1)
    decoder_h_1 = Dense(decoder_dim, activation=activ)
    decoder_h_2 = decoder_h_1(zc)
    decoder_out_1 = Dense(decoder_out_dim, activation='sigmoid')
    decoder_out_2 = decoder_out_1(decoder_h_2)
    decoder_out_2 = Reshape((seconds * frequency_x, 3))(decoder_out_2)
    decoder_model = Model([z_input, y_input], decoder_out_2)
    decoder_model.summary()
    return decoder_model

def vae_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    recon = K.sum(K.binary_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true), axis=1)
    kl = (0.5 * K.sum((K.exp(sigma) + K.square(mu) - 1. - sigma ), axis=-1))
    return recon + kl

def recon_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sum(K.binary_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true), axis=1)

def kl_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return (0.5 * K.sum((K.exp(sigma) + K.square(mu) - 1. - sigma ), 1))

def build_cvae():
    encoder_model = build_cvae_encoder()
    decoder_model = build_cvae_decoder()

    x_input, y_input = encoder_model.input
    print("x_input.shape: ", x_input.shape, "y_input.shape: ", y_input.shape)
    encoder_output = encoder_model.output
    print("encoder_output.shape: ", encoder_output.shape)

    decoder_out = decoder_model([encoder_output, y_input])

    cvae = Model([x_input, y_input], decoder_out)
    cvae.compile(optimizer=optim, loss=vae_loss, metrics=[recon_loss, kl_loss])
    cvae.summary()
    return cvae, encoder_model, decoder_model

def train_cvae(models, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
    batch_size_train = min(X_train.shape[0] // (seconds * frequency_x), 
                        y_train.shape[0] // (seconds * frequency_y))
    batch_size_test = min(X_test.shape[0] // (seconds * frequency_x),
                        y_test.shape[0] // (seconds * frequency_y))
    cvae, encoder_model, decoder_model = models
    # Convert the X_train, y_train to the format of
    # [batch_size, seconds * frequency_x, 3]
    # [batch_size, seconds * frequency_y, 2]
    print(X_train[: batch_size_train * seconds * frequency_x].shape, y_train[: batch_size_train * seconds * frequency_y].shape)
    X_train = np.reshape(X_train[: batch_size_train * seconds * frequency_x], (batch_size_train, seconds * frequency_x, 3))
    y_train = np.reshape(y_train[: batch_size_train * seconds * frequency_y], (batch_size_train, seconds * frequency_y, 2))
    X_test = np.reshape(X_test[: batch_size_test * seconds * frequency_x], (batch_size_test, seconds * frequency_x, 3))
    y_test = np.reshape(y_test[: batch_size_test * seconds * frequency_y], (batch_size_test, seconds * frequency_y, 2))

    print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape)
    _ = cvae.fit(x=[X_train, y_train], y=X_train,
                    validation_data=([X_test, y_test], X_test),
                    epochs=n_epoch, batch_size=batch_size_train)

    encoder_model.save_weights('cvae_encoder.h5')
    cvae.save_weights('cvae.h5')
    return cvae

### Prediction
def construct_numvec(digit, z=None):
    out = np.zeros((1, seconds * frequency_y, 2))
    out[:, digit] = 1.
    return (out)


def cvae_predict(cvae_model, digit):
    sample_3 = construct_numvec(digit)

    plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))
    rand_input = np.random.rand(seconds * frequency_x, 3)
    rand_input = np.expand_dims(rand_input, axis=0)
    plt.imshow(cvae_model.predict([rand_input, sample_3[:,:10]]).reshape(28,28), cmap = plt.cm.gray)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()

# main
def main():

    models = build_cvae()
    train_cvae(models, X_train_acce, y_train_acce, X_test_acce, y_test_acce)
    cvae_model, encoder_model, decoder_model = models

    # cvae_model.load_weights('cvae.h5')

    cvae_predict(cvae_model, 4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this code, I have been trying to use pictures and accelerometer data as my input data. Therefore, the input data are (seconds * frequency_x / frequency_y).

The error indications are below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\......\Desktop\evasion\Synthetic-Data-Generator-\cVAE_train_2D.py", line 167, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\......\Desktop\evasion\Synthetic-Data-Generator-\cVAE_train_2D.py", line 159, in main
    train_cvae(models, X_train_acce, y_train_acce, X_test_acce, y_test_acce)
  File "c:\Users\......\Desktop\evasion\Synthetic-Data-Generator-\cVAE_train_2D.py", line 130, in train_cvae
    _ = cvae.fit(x=[X_train, y_train], y=X_train,
  File "C:\Users\......\anaconda3\envs\env39\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training_v1.py", line 856, in fit
    return func.fit(
  File "C:\Users\......\anaconda3\envs\env39\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training_arrays_v1.py", line 734, in fit
    return fit_loop(
  File "C:\Users\......\anaconda3\envs\env39\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training_arrays_v1.py", line 421, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "C:\Users\......\anaconda3\envs\env39\lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend.py", line 4609, in __call__
    fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals, run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\......\anaconda3\envs\env39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1505, in __call__
    ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [5,3] vs. [5]
         [[{{node training/Adam/gradients/gradients/loss/model_1_loss/add_4_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]]
```

The summary of the model is below:

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to
==================================================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)        [(None, 30, 2)]              0         []

 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 300, 3)]             0         []

 dense (Dense)               (None, 30, 3)                9         ['input_2[0][0]']

 concatenate (Concatenate)   (None, 330, 3)               0         ['input_1[0][0]',
                                                                     'dense[0][0]']

 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 330, 512)             2048      ['concatenate[0][0]']

 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 330, 2)               1026      ['dense_1[0][0]']

 tf_op_layer_reduce_std/red  [(None, 1, 2)]               0         ['dense_3[0][0]']
 uce_variance/Mean (TensorF
 lowOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_reduce_std/red  [(None, 330, 2)]             0         ['dense_3[0][0]',
 uce_variance/sub (TensorFl                                          'tf_op_layer_reduce_std/reduc
 owOpLayer)                                                         e_variance/Mean[0][0]']

 tf_op_layer_reduce_std/red  [(None, 330, 2)]             0         ['tf_op_layer_reduce_std/reduc
 uce_variance/Square (Tenso                                         e_variance/sub[0][0]']
 rFlowOpLayer)

 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 330, 2)               1026      ['dense_1[0][0]']

 tf_op_layer_reduce_std/red  [(None, 2)]                  0         ['tf_op_layer_reduce_std/reduc
 uce_variance/Mean_1 (Tenso                                         e_variance/Square[0][0]']
 rFlowOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_Mean (TensorFl  [(None, 2)]                  0         ['dense_2[0][0]']
 owOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_reduce_std/Sqr  [(None, 2)]                  0         ['tf_op_layer_reduce_std/reduc
 t (TensorFlowOpLayer)                                              e_variance/Mean_1[0][0]']

 lambda (Lambda)             (None, 2)                    0         ['tf_op_layer_Mean[0][0]',
                                                                     'tf_op_layer_reduce_std/Sqrt[
                                                                    0][0]']

==================================================================================================
Total params: 4109 (16.05 KB)
Trainable params: 4109 (16.05 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to
==================================================================================================
 input_4 (InputLayer)        [(None, 30, 2)]              0         []

 input_3 (InputLayer)        [(None, 2)]                  0         []

 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 60)                   0         ['input_4[0][0]']

 concatenate_1 (Concatenate  (None, 62)                   0         ['input_3[0][0]',
 )                                                                   'flatten[0][0]']

 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 512)                  32256     ['concatenate_1[0][0]']

 dense_5 (Dense)             (None, 900)                  461700    ['dense_4[0][0]']

 reshape (Reshape)           (None, 300, 3)               0         ['dense_5[0][0]']

==================================================================================================
Total params: 493956 (1.88 MB)
Trainable params: 493956 (1.88 MB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
x_input.shape:  (None, 300, 3) y_input.shape:  (None, 30, 2)
encoder_output.shape:  (None, 2)
Model: "model_2"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to
==================================================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)        [(None, 30, 2)]              0         []

 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 300, 3)]             0         []

 dense (Dense)               (None, 30, 3)                9         ['input_2[0][0]']

 concatenate (Concatenate)   (None, 330, 3)               0         ['input_1[0][0]',
                                                                     'dense[0][0]']

 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 330, 512)             2048      ['concatenate[0][0]']

 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 330, 2)               1026      ['dense_1[0][0]']

 tf_op_layer_reduce_std/red  [(None, 1, 2)]               0         ['dense_3[0][0]']
 uce_variance/Mean (TensorF
 lowOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_reduce_std/red  [(None, 330, 2)]             0         ['dense_3[0][0]',
 uce_variance/sub (TensorFl                                          'tf_op_layer_reduce_std/reduc
 owOpLayer)                                                         e_variance/Mean[0][0]']

 tf_op_layer_reduce_std/red  [(None, 330, 2)]             0         ['tf_op_layer_reduce_std/reduc
 uce_variance/Square (Tenso                                         e_variance/sub[0][0]']
 rFlowOpLayer)

 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 330, 2)               1026      ['dense_1[0][0]']

 tf_op_layer_reduce_std/red  [(None, 2)]                  0         ['tf_op_layer_reduce_std/reduc
 uce_variance/Mean_1 (Tenso                                         e_variance/Square[0][0]']
 rFlowOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_Mean (TensorFl  [(None, 2)]                  0         ['dense_2[0][0]']
 owOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_reduce_std/Sqr  [(None, 2)]                  0         ['tf_op_layer_reduce_std/reduc
 t (TensorFlowOpLayer)                                              e_variance/Mean_1[0][0]']

 lambda (Lambda)             (None, 2)                    0         ['tf_op_layer_Mean[0][0]',
                                                                     'tf_op_layer_reduce_std/Sqrt[
                                                                    0][0]']

 model_1 (Functional)        (None, 300, 3)               493956    ['lambda[0][0]',
                                                                     'input_2[0][0]']

==================================================================================================
Total params: 498065 (1.90 MB)
Trainable params: 498065 (1.90 MB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I really do not quite understand why this would happen. I would really appreciate it if someone could give me some suggestion.

Thank you!

I have been working on debugging it. Also, I read similar posts on stackoverflow. One of the posts is really simiar to my problem. The post suggests that we should not include batch_size in our model. I checked the input layer, but I did not find similar problem in my code.

Comment: I have already solved this problem. I found that it's due to the different value of batch_size_train and batch_size_test caused this problem. I think fit() method does not allow us to use different sizes of train size and test size.